# ModelAttribute should have already been expanded via ExpandedParameterBuilderPlugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

For the annotation @ModelAttribute i am getting the WARN log:

> @ModelAttribute annotated parameters should have already been expanded via the ExpandedParameterBuilderPlugin

Causing class is ParameterTypeReader, package springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.
I am using @ModelAttribute in my Controllers. How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelAttribute annotation should be avoided for primitive Types like int and String. Use request param or path variable instead.